# Connecting to MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I currently have Spring configured to use HSQL, but I would like to use MySQL. What needs to change?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001"/>
        <property name="username" value="monty"/>
        <property name="password" value="indian"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>uk.co.vinoth.spring.domain.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserDAO" class="uk.co.vinoth.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/user/*.htm" class="uk.co.vinoth.spring.web.UserController" >
        <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the following properties:

```
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/schema"/>

    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
```

(where 'schema' is your mysql database name, assuming your mysql host is 127.0.0.1)

And add the mysql-connector jar to your classpath.

Comment: Or, if you are use InnoDB, change the `hibernate.dialect` value to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`.

Comment: I believe MySQL5Dialect and MySQL5InnoDBDialect are also options.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to change the `driverClass` and `url` properties of the `DataSource`.

`driverClass` should be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
`url` should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname`

Answer (score 1):

A good example of using mysql with java in spring is detailed on the [mysql website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee.html#connector-j-usagenotes-spring-config)

The hibernate should be as noted in the answer by ivy.